# C unit testing mocking of "private" functions

Tags: c, unit-testing, module, mocking

I am trying to implement TDD in C coding. I am building the program structure in a quite modularised way and using as atomic functions as possible. I make one test file (including several suits) for one module (module = header file + source file). I am struggling to make the program files "not know that they are being tested", in other words - I don't want testing parts of code in the proper program. Therefore almost often I need to include the source file in the test file in order to have access to the "private" variables and functions.

**That was the intro, now the problem:** if in a module I have an `aaa()` function, which uses inside a `bbb()` function, which uses some `xxx()` function from an external module, I can easily test the `bbb()` function in the *atomic* way by mocking the `x()` function: `#define bbb mock_bbb` and providing a mock *xxx* module for `#include`. However, I am unable to find a way of *atomic* testing of the `aaa()` function, which uses a function from the same module. Is it possible to do? *(note, that apart of mocking `bbb()` for `aaa()`, I have to be also able to use the original `bbb()` to test it)*

---

My closest try was to use `-Wl,-wrap,xxx`, but the problem is that I haven't found a way to automate this *(wildcard or something?)* - I will have almost 100 testing files, each containing several functions to test - I cannot allow myself to put manually every function in the `makefile`.

Comment: Take a look. http://eradman.com/posts/tdd-in-c.html

Comment: Another possibility is to write the code in C, but use [googlemock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) for testing. It is meant for C++ code, but you can compile your code with `g++` for running the tests.

Comment: Thanks for the sources. I had already considered googlemock or cmock, but is strongly coupled with C++ way of thinking, classes etc. I want to avoid introducing another language to our otherwise complicated build process, so for me that's a _no_. As to the first article, all the solutions either don't work with _private_ functions (which is what I really care about) or still need interference in the proper program, which is what I would also very much like to avoid.

Comment: What if you change the way your modules work? You said you can mock functions from external modules, but private functions can't be mocked since they are on the same file. What if you split your source file in two files, one containing public functions and the other with only private functions; that way, you can mock the private ones. Essentially, `aaa()` on public file of module `a`, `bbb()` on private file of module `a`, and `xxx()` on public file of module `x` (or private, if `xxx()` is private).

Comment: Not if one private function uses another private function - they would be still in one file and I wouldn't be able to _unit test_ the one that uses the other.

Comment: You are correct, but it is considered bad practice to test private functions. They should be integrated tested by writing good tests for public functions. Testing private functions will only make your code extremely brittle. [Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M) (it is Ruby, but the concepts still apply).

Comment: By the way, if you really want to test private functions no matter what, then my suggestion is that you use private and public files as I have suggested earlier; then, on your private function, you change their signatures in order to accept function pointers. That way you can easily mock other private functions and just pass pointers for the mocks; it also won't impact code API much since their are private.

Comment: As to the first comment - it's nothing unusual that major part of a module is encapsulated and does all the magic behind the scenes of the module interface exposed to the user. Exposing only the necessary part is also considered a good practice but then I would like to unit-test the more important, hidden part.

As to the second comment - I think pointers are a good idea, looks like a reasonable compromise. However, then there's no point in splitting the file into two, since I would make the function pointers private anyway (and include the source file directly in the test file like I do now).

Comment: Unit-testing private functions is still considered a bad thing. There are other ways to ensure their correctness. They should be valid if your unit-tests covering public functions all pass. Also, if you want a more reliable way, you should use assertions on your code (even on public functions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93530/discussion-between-jalooc-and-cenouro).

Answer (score 0):

I never test "private" functions in an atomic way. I usually unit-test a c-module using its public functions and checking its calls to other modules (using mocks through dependency injection) and checking its private data members (by exposing its private data members with a GetDataPtr()-function that is compiled only for the unit test project).

For me that the best tradeof between effort and complexity of the unit test framework, although it not possible to reach 100% statement coverage in some "private" functions.

Comment: But if you test modules as a whole, it's not really a _unit testing_ strictly saying, is it? And what type of **dependency injection** are you using? Something like me with mock, empty headers and `#define f()` mocking?

Comment: I think it is still a unittest but a bit more from a black-box-view.

Comment: For depency injection, I'm using function pointers which are linked in an init() function. For the unit test, I call the the init() function with my mocked test-function.

Comment: But the `init()` function is a part of a proper program module or a part of unit test module?